# Проверка пересечения фигур

Tags: c#

Есть класс фигуры у которой в поле хранится тип(1 - прямоугольник, 2 - отрезок, 3 - круг), нужно написать метод проверки имеются ли общие точки у любой фигуры с прямоугольником. Фигура хранится 2 координатами: верняя левая и правая нижняя, для окружности первая координата - центр, а вторая коородината значение радиуса.

Вот сам класс:

```
public class Figure
{
    public Figures Type { get;}
    public int Color { get;}
    public Point Top { get;}
    public Point Bottom { get;}
    public double Square => GetSquare();

    public Figure(int type, int topX, int topY, int bottomX, int bottomY, int color)
    {
        Type = (Figures)type;
        Top = new Point(topX, topY);
        Bottom = new Point(bottomX, bottomY);
        if (type == (int) Figures.Circle)
            Bottom.Y = 0;
        Color = color;
    }

    public bool AreIntersected(Figure other)
    {
        if(other.Type is Figures.Rectangle)
            return Top.X<= other.Bottom.X && other.Top.X <= Bottom.X && Top.Y <= other.Bottom.Y && other.Top.Y <= Bottom.Y;
        else if (other.Type is Figures.Segment)
            return false;
        else
            return false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Но этот метод для проверки пересечения прямоугольников не работает.
Как проще всего проверять пересечение любой фигуры с заданным прямоугольним?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, давайте вспомним принципы ООП, и будем кодировать фигуры не числом, а типом фигуры.

Получаем:

```
public abstract class Figure
{
    public int Color { get; }
    public abstract bool AreIntersected(Figure other);
}
```

и его конкретные реализации:

```
public class Rectangle : Figure
{
    public Point TopLeft { get; }
    public Point BottomRight { get; }
    public override bool AreIntersected(Figure other) { ... }
}

public class Circle : Figure
{
    public Point Center { get; }
    public double Radius { get; }
    public override bool AreIntersected(Figure other) { ... }
}

public class Segment : Figure
{
    public Point Start { get; }
    public Point End { get; }
    public override bool AreIntersected(Figure other) { ... }
}
```

Теперь, как реализовать функцию `AreIntersected`? Вам придётся перебрать все возможные комбинации фигур. Это достаточно длинная, скучная, неприятная работа. Я вам покажу начало, а дальше вы сами.

```
public class Rectangle : Figure
{
    public Point TopLeft { get; }
    public Point BottomRight { get; }
    public bool override AreIntersected(Figure other)
    {
        if (other is Rectangle rect)
            return AreIntersected(rect);
        else if (other is Circle circle)
            return AreIntersected(circle);
        else if (other is Segment segment)
            return AreIntersected(segment);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown figure type: {other}")
    }

    // случай двух прямоугольников
    bool AreIntersected(Rectangle other)
    {
        if (this.TopLeft.X > other.BottomRight.X)
            return false;
        if (other.TopLeft.X > this.BottomRight.X)
            return false;
        if (this.TopLeft.Y > other.BottomRight.Y)
            return false;
        if (other.TopLeft.Y > this.BottomRight.Y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    // случай двух прямоугольника и отрезка
    bool AreIntersected(Segment other)
    {
        var bottomLeft = new Point(topLeft.X, bottomRight.Y);
        var topRight = new Point(bottomRight.X, topRight.Y);
        var intersection =
            other.GetIntersection(new HalfPlane(new Axis(bottomLeft, TopLeft))
                 .GetIntersection(new HalfPlane(new Axis(BottomRight, bottomLeft))
                 .GetIntersection(new HalfPlane(new Axis(topRight, BottomRight))
                 .GetIntersection(new HalfPlane(new Axis(TopLeft, topRight));
        return !intersection.IsEmpty();
    }

    // случай прямоугольника и круга
    bool AreIntersected(Circle other)
    {
        // реализуйте сами
    }
}
```

Вам придётся существенно расширить вашу геометрическую библиотеку. Дерзайте!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, и замечание по поводу ООП, но в задании четко указано, что тип хранит класс фигуры как свойство, так как эти фигуры являются элементами списка, т.е долны быть одного типа. Не суть дела, не могли бы вы объяснить работу метода для прямоугольника и отрезка, а конкретно метод GetIntersection и откуда взялся он и HalfPlane, Axis. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: @Banged: Являются элементами списка — не значит, что должны быть одного типа. В иерархии типов, которую я описал, вы можете положить все фигуры в `List<Figure>`.

Comment: @Banged: `HalfPlane` и `Axis` нету, это вам придётся написать самостоятельно. `HalfPlane` представляет полуплоскость, лежащую справа от оси `Axis`. `Axis` представляет направленную прямую, то есть, ось.